# Highlight.js Vue Plugin systematically ignores language value passed to it

Tags: vuejs3, prop, highlightjs

Whether I call the plugin directly from my template section or mount it programmatically while passing to it a `language` prop value, the language I specify always ends up being ignored by the plugin who instead chooses himself a language.

From template section:

```
<highlightjs language='javascript' code="var x = 5;" />
```

From script section (programmatically):

```
<template>
  <div class="myElement"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
// some code here...

nextTick(() => {
  mount(HighlightPlugin.component, {
    element: document.querySelector('.myElement'),
    props: {
      language: 'javascript',
      code: codeSnippet
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

Here's how the plugin is imported in my `main.js`:

```
import 'highlight.js/styles/github-dark-dimmed.css'
import 'highlight.js/lib/common'
import hljsVuePlugin from '@highlightjs/vue-plugin'
app.use(hljsVuePlugin)

app.mount('#app')
```

EDIT - updated version:

```
import 'highlight.js/styles/github-dark-dimmed.css'
import 'highlight.js/lib/common'
import hljsVuePlugin from '@highlightjs/vue-plugin'
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core'
import javascript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/javascript'
hljs.registerLanguage('javascript', javascript)
app.use(hljsVuePlugin)

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: where `mount(HighlightPlugin.component ...` is located? please share the whole script

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim in a component - I edited my question to add more information.

Comment: I’m not good in this stuff still 
`import 'highlight.js/styles/github-dark-dimmed.css'
import 'highlight.js/lib/common'
import hljsVuePlugin from '@highlightjs/vue-plugin'
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core'
import javascript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/javascript'

hljs.registerLanguage('javascript', javascript)
app.use(hljsVuePlugin)

app.mount('#app')`

Answer (score 0):

Beside the current [`highlightjs/vue-plugin` issue 49](https://github.com/highlightjs/vue-plugin/issues/49), you have the 2021 [`highlightjs/vue-plugin` issue 8 "`language` setting is not effective"](https://github.com/highlightjs/vue-plugin/issues/8): there might be problems when different versions of Highlight.js are present in the project's dependency tree. A workaround suggested involved manually installing a specific version of Highlight.js (version 10.7.2), which resolved the issue for a user. But there might be compatibility concerns with newer versions of Highlight.js.
The a `console.log(hljs.version);`.

Make sure you import it explicitly in your `main.js` or wherever you configure Highlight.js:

```js
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core';
import javascript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/javascript';
import 'highlight.js/styles/github-dark-dimmed.css';
hljs.registerLanguage('javascript', javascript);
```

Double-check if there is any code that might be overwriting the `language` prop or if the plugin has default behavior when it fails to recognize the specified language. That could happen if the language module was not imported.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import 'highlight.js/styles/github-dark-dimmed.css';
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core';
import javascript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/javascript';
import hljsVuePlugin from '@highlightjs/vue-plugin';

// Register the JavaScript language
hljs.registerLanguage('javascript', javascript);

Vue.use(hljsVuePlugin);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

---

> It is still not working and there is nothing overwriting the language prop - just me passing value javascript to the language prop when calling the plugin.
> I did not have highlight.js installed, only `@highlightjs/vue-plugin`.
> I installed it (`package.json: "highlight.js": "^11.9.0"`), but it does not make any difference.

Then try and implement a diagnostic script in your Vue project:

```js
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import hljs from 'highlight.js';

export default {
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      // Debug function to check language availability
      function debugHighlightJs() {
        // List of languages you want to check
        const languagesToCheck = ['javascript', 'python', 'html'];
        languagesToCheck.forEach((lang) => {
          if (hljs.getLanguage(lang)) {
            console.log(`Language loaded: ${lang}`);
          } else {
            console.error(`Language not found: ${lang}`);
          }
        });
        // Attempt to highlight a simple code snippet
        const code = 'const x = 5;';
        const result = hljs.highlight(code, { language: 'javascript' });
        console.log(`Highlight result: ${result.value}`);
      }

      // Call the debug function
      debugHighlightJs();
    });
  },
}
```

That way, you will see the currently used Highlight.js version. And you will check if the specified languages are correctly registered and available.
You can also test with this script if a simple JavaScript code snippet is correctly highlighted.

The goal is to see if the issue lies with language detection or plugin integration.

Comment: Unsure what giving the link to my GH issue was about but it's still not working and there's nothing overwriting the language prop - just me passing value `javascript` to the `language` prop when calling the plugin. I did not have `highlight.js` installed, only `@highlightjs/vue-plugin`. I installed it (`package.json`: `"highlight.js": "^11.9.0",`) but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @drake035 I have edited the answer to suggest some diagnostic ideas, to help pinpoint the issue. Let me know what you find.

Comment: Thank you @VonC. Getting `app.mounted is not a function` error, any idea how to work around that?

Comment: @drake035 I suspect `mounted` is a [lifecycle hook in Vue components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle), not a method on the Vue application instance created by `createApp`. To run code after the app is mounted, you should place it in the `mounted` hook of a Vue component, or alternatively, use the `app.mount()` method's callback if you need to execute code right after the app has been mounted globally. I have edited the answer to fix the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks VonC (can't alias you, not sure why??). Getting this result: https://imgur.com/a/j5lLyGF. Or in plain text: `<span class="hljs-keyword">const</span> x = <span class="hljs-number">5</span>;`. In other words, although the languages are correctly loaded, the class for javascript does *not* get applied. Could this plugin be actually faulty?

Comment: @drake035 So the issue is that the plugin is not applying the appropriate CSS classes for syntax highlighting. Is there any error message in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: it's not just the class - depending on the language class assigned to the wrapper `<code>` element, the plugin does all kinds of things differently inside it (wrapping vs not wrapping each DOM node and applying certain one class or another to them). No error in console.

Comment: @drake035 Strange. That could be a bug to report.

Comment: well I created a GH as you know but nobody hast replied yet. Anyway thanks!